# Can I use intercepting routes with /pages directory rather than /app in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I read [this page from Next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes) about intercepting routes, and I am trying to build it into my app. Specifically, I want a modal to pop up when I click a button, but then if the user refreshes the page the modal is fullscreen. However, the docs are describing an /app directory, while mine still uses /pages. I am trying to do the following:

```
pages
| (.)photo
| | [id].tsx
| photo
| | [id].tsx
```

My hope was that when I call `router.push('/photo/'+id);` I would get the modal, but I just end up on the page. Is this just impossible to do or am I missing something? Do I need to migrate the whole thing to /app for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, intercepting routes are only available in the app router.

You can note they are only listed under app (and not pages) here: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure#parallel-and-intercepted-routes

You don't need to upgrade your entire app to the app directory to make use of the intercept routing though, just the bits that rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

I also still finding the way for page router. Hopefully they will support it in the future .
I query the route and mask the url with as value in router.push . It will works like interception route and when we refresh it will redirect to actual page . But we have to handle the component ourself . Example when user query exists display the user interception route component.

```
router.push({query:{user:'JohnDoe'},'mask_value')
```